# WPF datagrid rowHeader object

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am working on Datagrid RowHeader mouse over thing.

How would I get DataGridRowHeader from rowIndex.

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
<EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="OnMouseEnter"/>
</Style>

private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //your logic here
}
```

you can add MouseLeave to the style if that helps your logic